# how to search keyword in comment in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

When I read large open source project, I think the author's comment will be very useful, so I want to search for the keyword in the comment.

I already search the answer on the *stackoverflow*, I get the method to search the keyword in the `//` comment.

But things is: it will be a little troublesome when you want to search the multiline comment like `/* multiline-comment */` by using regex,

`StartOfExpression.*\r?\n.*EndOfExpression` and this way seems just work in the two line comment, there are many comments have more than 2 lines.

So, is there a better way to get the keyword in this multi line comment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search in multi line comments try this regex

```
\/\*[\S\s]*?(yourSearchTerm)[\S\s]*?\*\/
```